# lua match repeating pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I need to encapsulate in some way pattern in lua pattern matching to find whole sequence of this pattern in string. What do I mean by that.
For example we have string like that:
`"word1,word2,word3,,word4,word5,word6,       word7,"`
I need to match first sequence of words followed by coma (`word1,word2,word3,`)

In python I would use this pattern `"(\w+,)+"`, but similar pattern in lua (like `(%w+,)+`), will return just `nil`, because brackets in lua patterns means completely different thing.

I hope now you see my problem.
Is there a way to do repeating patterns in lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example wasn't too clear in terms of what should happen to the `word4,word5,word6` and        `word7,`

This would give you any seqence of comma separated words without white space or empty positions.

```
local text = "word1,word2,word3,,word4,word5,word6,       word7,"
-- replace any comma followed by any white space or comma
--- by a comma and a single white space
text = text:gsub(",[%s,]+", ", ")
-- then match any sequence of >=1 non-whitespace characters
for sequence in text:gmatch("%S+,") do
  print(sequence)
end
```

Prints

```
word1,word2,word3,
word4,word5,word6,
word7,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily using LPeg if that's available to you:

```lua
local lpeg = require "lpeg"
local str = "word1,word2,word3,,word4,word5,word6,       word7,"
local word = (lpeg.R"az"+lpeg.R"AZ"+lpeg.R"09") ^ 1
local sequence = lpeg.C((word * ",") ^1)

print(sequence:match(str))
```